# Display L.marker without icon

Tags: leaflet, markers, icon

Would like to start my leaflet map without any features displayed on start. The feature should not be displayed before a location is found via my search.control.

I started with

```
// first "invisible" icon
var smallIcon = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: 'mypicture',
    iconRetinaUrl: 'mypicture',
    iconSize:    [0.00, 0.00],
    iconAnchor:  [0, 0],
    popupAnchor: [1, -34],
    shadowSize:  [0, 0]
});

// second "visible" icon
var smallIcon2 = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: 'mypicture',
    iconRetinaUrl: 'mypicture',
    iconSize:    [25, 41],
    iconAnchor:  [12, 41],
    popupAnchor: [1, -34],
    shadowUrl: 'mypicture',
    shadowSize:  [41, 41]
});

// adding geojson and display feautures with "invisible" marker
var marker;
var json_AlleJSON = new L.geoJson(myjson, {
    onEachFeature: pop_All,                     
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        marker = new L.marker(latlng, {icon: smallIcon});
        return marker;
    }
});
```

And to change the icon when location is found:

```
// changing the icon to "visible"
searchControl.on('search_locationfound', function(e) {
    sidebar.hide();
    e.layer.setIcon(smallIcon2); 
});
```

This actually works **BUT** the problem I got: even by reducing the iconSize to 0.0, the map interacting gets so slow because of loading an image for every feature (my json contains about 100 entries).

I tried to solve this by leaving the iconUrl empty but this didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: The proper approach to this is to load the results (and layer) when the locationfound event occurs. You don't need to create the layer before hand, or if you do, just leave it in the map, without records. After the location is found, populate the layer.

Comment: and how is that possible? if i remove 'return marker' and add it to the locationfound process, ill dont get any results in my search bar...

Comment: canceled this... didnt find i way to make the leaflet work fluent. went back to l.circlemarker

Answer (score 6):

What if you created a transparent [`L.DivIcon`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#divicon) for your first invisible image?  (This technique is used in the [Leaflet.draw plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw).)

From [Leaflet.draw's javascript source code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/master/src/draw/handler/Draw.Polyline.js#L86):

```
var marker = L.marker(this._map.getCenter(), {
                icon: L.divIcon({
                    className: 'leaflet-mouse-marker',
                    iconAnchor: [20, 20],
                    iconSize: [40, 40]
                }),
                opacity: 0,
                zIndexOffset: this.options.zIndexOffset
            });
```

and from the css:

```
.leaflet-mouse-marker{background-color:#fff;cursor:crosshair}
```

I suspect you don't even need the css...just skip the class name.  I think the `opacity: 0` is the important part.  In any case, I've found for myself that `DivIcons` load much faster than images for regular markers.

Comment: Thanks for this advice! I already tried this. It does not boost the performance a lot. By using L.circleMarker instead of L.marker everything works much (!) smoother.