# Leaflet : Auto-creations of markers on Polyline

Tags: leaflet

I am new to to Leaflet. I am drawing polylines on map but markers are pinned automatically (unwanted). Please suggest me that how can avoid auto-creation of marker (`<img ...>`)

I was using chrome-Javascript debugger to find root-cause & I observed that when `.addTo(map)` is getting triggered, *leaflet.js* is placing markers by calling `_initIcon()`

### My function

which is drawing Polyline on map

```
function Leaflet_Overpass(map,osmDataAsXml,filterpane)
    {    
            var resultAsGeojson = osmtogeojson(osmDataAsXml);             
            var resultLayer = L.geoJson(resultAsGeojson, 
                    {
                        pane: filterpane,
                        style: function (feature) 
                        {
                            switch(filterpane)
                            {
                            case 'entity1': return {color: "#0000ff", "weight": 10, "opacity": 0.8};break;
                            case 'entity2': return {color: "#ff0000", "weight": 7, "opacity": 0.7};break;
                            }

                        },
                        filter: function (feature, layer) 
                        {
                            var isPolygon = (feature.geometry) && (feature.geometry.type !== undefined) && (feature.geometry.type === "Polygon");
                            if (isPolygon) 
                            {
                                feature.geometry.type = "Point";
                                var polygonCenter = L.latLngBounds(feature.geometry.coordinates[0]).getCenter();
                                feature.geometry.coordinates = [ polygonCenter.lat, polygonCenter.lng ];
                            }
                            return true;
                        },
                        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) 
                        {                               
                            var popupContent = "<h2>"+ feature.properties.tags.name + "</h2><a href=\"https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/" + feature.properties.id +"\">"+feature.properties.type + " : "+feature.properties.id+"</a>";                                             
                            layer.bindPopup(popupContent);                              
                        }
                    }).addTo(map); 
            return;
    }
```

#### Leflet.js Code

which is placing marker

```
_initIcon: function() {
            var t = this.options
              , i = "leaflet-zoom-" + (this._zoomAnimated ? "animated" : "hide")
              , e = t.icon.createIcon(this._icon)
              , n = !1;
            e !== this._icon && (this._icon && this._removeIcon(),
            n = !0,
            t.title && (e.title = t.title),
            "IMG" === e.tagName && (e.alt = t.alt || "")),
            pt(e, i),
            t.keyboard && (e.tabIndex = "0"),
            this._icon = e,
            t.riseOnHover && this.on({
                mouseover: this._bringToFront,
                mouseout: this._resetZIndex
            });
            var o = t.icon.createShadow(this._shadow)
              , s = !1;
            o !== this._shadow && (this._removeShadow(),
            s = !0),
            o && (pt(o, i),
            o.alt = ""),
            this._shadow = o,
            t.opacity < 1 && this._updateOpacity(),
            n && this.getPane().appendChild(this._icon),
            this._initInteraction(),
            o && s && this.getPane("shadowPane").appendChild(this._shadow)
        },
```

Comment: Does the GeoJSON from Overpass contain points, polylines, polygons, or a combination of those? What happens if you feed some GeoJSON with *just* polylines?

Comment: my dataflow is `Overpass provides *.osm(xml) file` >> `converst osm file to Geojson thru javascript` >> `leaflet.js renders polyline / gorup of polylines thru above function`

Comment: Once again: Does that GeoJSON have point geometries in it?

Comment: `type: "FeatureCollection"`

Comment: GeoJSON file outline... `features: Array(3)
0: {type: "Feature", id: "way/29145251", properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
1: {type: "Feature", id: "node/320607347", properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
2: {type: "Feature", id: "node/320607391", properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
type: "FeatureCollection"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution thru [StackExchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221941/display-l-marker-without-icon) : By default, Leaflet assigns marker to layers, hence if we want to avoid marker in markerpane-div, then we should declare

> dummy icon-marker with 0size in pointToLayer

.

## Solution

```
function Leaflet_Overpass(map,osmDataAsXml,filterpane)
{    
        .....
        var smallIcon = new L.Icon({
            iconUrl: 'dummy',
            iconRetinaUrl: 'dummy',
            iconSize:    [0.00, 0.00],
            iconAnchor:  [0, 0],
            popupAnchor: [1, -34],
            shadowSize:  [0, 0]
        });
        
        var resultLayer = L.geoJson(resultAsGeojson, 
                {
                    ...,
                    pointToLayer:function (feature, latlng) 
                    {
                        return L.marker(latlng, {icon: smallIcon});
                    },
                    ...
                 }).addTo(map); 
        return;
}
```